# How can I use JavaScript to add a year from the current date?

Tags: javascript

I have "Date this Form Completed" and "Expire Date" I want the expire date to automatically be 1 year from the date this form completed box. I don't know enough about JavaScript to do this but wanted to know if it's possible?

thanks
Anthony

Comment: One of the first results from google has the answer to this: https://www.learningpenguin.net/myblog/2013/01/18/add-days-months-and-years-in-javascript/

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like this:

```
var d = new Date();
d.setFullYear(d.getFullYear() + 1);
```

Comment: Where would I put this code (under calculations)? and is that all I would need to enter?

Comment: @AnthonyWebb It's hard to say you should post some code so we can better help you.

Comment: I don't have any code. That's what I was asking initially. I just have my form with the "Date Form Completed" and "Expire Date" boxes. I'm truly a novice with JavaScript and just wanted to know if I could have the "Expire Date" box auto fill based on the date I enter into "Date Form Completed" box